# Spring - Inject Instance Of Class with Only Static Members

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a class `Foo` in package `com.example.dao` -

```
@Component
public class Foo {
    public static final String nameAbc = "Abc";
    public static final String nameDef = "Def";
    public static List<String> getNames() {
        return ImmutableList.of(nameAbc, nameDef);
    }

    // I created this for testing purpose.
    // I was testing if maybe Spring needs an instance of class to inject.
    public static Foo instance = new Foo();
}
```

In a `Configuration` BeanConfig class I wish to inject a `List<Foo>` and perform some operator on it -

```
@Configuration
public class BeanConfig {

    private List<Foo> foos;

    @Autowired
    public void setFoos(List<Foo> foos) {this.foos = foos;}

    @Bean
    public Bar bar() {
        // using foos in some logic here for creating Bar bean
    }
}
```

I have also tried using `@ComponentScan` on `BeanConfig` class -

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.dao")
```

but class Foo is still not injected as I get an empty list. What exactly is the mistake here?

**Update -**
It came out to be a different issue - some beans in `com.example.dao` package did not had default constructors which caused `@ComponentScan` to throw an exception while creating their instances. Updating the constructors resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I used Spring Boot to test your code. Please check your configuration
2016-12-21 20:45:36.326  INFO 25224 --- [           main] com.mycompany.app.Application            : Started Application in 11.997 seconds (JVM running for 12.861)

Result: [Abc, Def]

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    @PostConstruct
    public void initApplication() throws IOException {
        LOGGER.info("Running with Spring profile(s) : {}", env.getActiveProfiles());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

        List<String> list = Foo.getNames();
        System.out.println(list);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It came out to be a different issue - some beans in com.example.dao package did not had default constructors which caused @ComponentScan to throw an exception while creating their instances. Updating the constructors resolved the issue.